# Assertion failure.Interface Builder encountered an internal logic error

Tags: iphone

**I am using SDK 4.2 and i got the error message while opening any interface builder.**

> Assertion failure
>
> Interface Builder encountered an
>   internal logic error. Choose
>   "Continue" to continue running
>   Interface Builder in an inconsistent
>   state.  Choose "Crash" to halt
>   Interface Builder and file a bug with
>   Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will
>   result in the loss of all unsaved
>   data.

Need help on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to go on here.

Basically, IB is crashing.  It could be the file you are opening or corrupted preferences.  Try deleting preferences or opening a known good nib/xib file.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me because I was using a badge icon on my UITabBarItem.

To fix it, I've opened my .xib file with an XML editor and I've deleted this line :

```
<string key="IBUIBadgeValue">4</string>
```

Hope this will help :)

PS : I've also added an image in my UITabBarItem object (but it didn't resolve it)

Comment: +1 As bizarre as this sounds, it really did help me. I was configuring some screenshots for my app, so I configured badge values in IB. After a project restart/reload, IB started croaking. And then it disappeared when I removed the badge value. Strange.